# Simple power line communication circuit PLC design?

Tags: modulation, power-line-communication

I need simple PLC power line communication design which I could transmit /receive a packet of data through two points ? 
Any block diagram with little details will be great for me  .

Update : 
Data speed doesn't matter , distance of transmission will be large (several kilometers ) , Data will be packets in 4 bytes +- 2 bytes, security is very important ,what's the available off-the-shelf products .

Comment: A little more information could be useful.  Such as: Desired data speed, quantity of data, distance of transmission, security requirements, why you can't just use an off-the-shelf product, etc.

Comment: @Matt Data speed doesn't matter , distance of transmission will be large (several kilometers ) , Data will be packets in 4 bytes +- 2 bytes, security is very important ,what's the available off-the-shelf products >??

Comment: Most off-the-shelf power line products rely on the two end-points being on the same phase of the same spur of the grid.  To go multiple kilometers could be an iffy prospect at best.  You have to a) get the signal through the intervening substations, b) get it on to the right phase, and c) not interfere with the operations of the electricity provider.

Comment: @Matt any examples , links I'm totally lost, and don't know where to start

Comment: Unless both endpoints are on the same phase of the same branch of the power grid (unlikely over such distances) then you have pretty much no chance.  The substation transformers will filter out any high frequencies.  The power companies are already using the low frequency ranges for control and automation.  Using anything higher than a few kilohertz will require special equipment at the substations to propagate the data.  Also, the power company won't like it ;)  I'd find a different way if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualcomm's [Atheros chipset](http://www.qca.qualcomm.com/technology/technology.php?nav1=52) and there are several commercial products based on it.

Comment: Atheros will not work here. As noted by others, if your signal has to transit a power transformer thenall except very low frequency signals will be filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the [Texas Instruments's PLC technology](http://goo.gl/1kKlD)?
And specifically the ["C2000 Power Line Modem Developer's Kit"](http://goo.gl/TwLeR)?

Answer (score 1):

I have used YITRAN PLC chips in the pass, but the signal doesnt jump the transformer.

I am now using MAXIM PLC chips with success, and the signals jumps the transformers to others phase lines. We got several kilometers coverage.

Comment: Interesting! But isn't that kit extremely expensive?

Comment: If you buy 100k pcs, then you have very competitive price.

Answer (score 0):

Majenko correctly remarked that over the requested 'few Km' you will be on different power branches of the electrical grid. So far there is no COTS that is specifically targeted to such application.
If I were you I'd pass to radio (there is plenty of radio modules around). But if
you are forced to work on PLC 
and you could afford a very long time for sending and receiving messages 
and you are sure there is a direct PL path between the two connected points 
then a DSSS modulator/demodulator at very low frequences (few KHz at most) could solve your problem.
The trouble is that you won't find chips to do that either and you'll have to build it from the ground-up.

Answer (score 0):

Being a student as far as I know, I would like to suggest you to use power line modem 1187 for serial transmission of data over power line.Digital input you may take from ARM or PIC controller for your modem.Use same circuit at the receiver to get the required data as you are taking the parameter to be controlled that means your input may be sensors like temperature or any other that you want to be controlled.